# Why use Gradle instead of Capistrano?

Tags: capistrano, gradle

I am new for both tools , And not getting completely .

Why Gradle is targeted for deployment if I am deploying with Capistrano ?

See also [Gradle Overview](http://gradle.org/overview).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gradle is built from the [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) programming language, and is considered a build language, and less of a deployment tool. You can perform compilation of JVM languages, package it, and upload it to a repository easily, but it has little strength in deployment of web applications, unless you are directly deploying a WAR or EAR file.

Capistrano is built from the [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) language, but is considered more powerful for deployment, and is less of a build language ([Rake](http://rake.rubyforge.org/) is the dominant Ruby build language). Capistrano's strength lies in being able to connect to a remote host, and execute commands on it, or copy out code to live on a webserver.

It is my opinion that Gradle would be a better language for all things JVM related, and Capistrano would be useful for PHP, Rails, or other types of web applications.

Comment: but gradle/groovy don't have the ssh magic that capistrano has (a non-trivial thing). I'd love a gradle/groovy equivalent.

Comment: I'm not sure will this help anyhow, but you can write own tasks in Gradle and execute shell commands via String object simply like `"ssh user@host 'do something remote'".execute()`

Answer (score 1):

Use [gradle-ssh-plugin](https://github.com/int128/gradle-ssh-plugin) with gradle as Capistrano replacement.

Here is an [usage example](http://java.dzone.com/articles/replace-your-scripts-gradle).